# How to prove that every graph admits an “almost-balanced” orientation?

Tags: graph-theory

Let an "almost-balanced" digraph be a digraph where, for all vertex v, $|_{in}degree(v)-_{out}degree(v)| <= 1$. How can I prove that every graph admits a almost-balanced orientation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove the edges of a multigraph may be oriented such that the net-degree of any vertex is $\leq 1$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396009/prove-the-edges-of-a-multigraph-may-be-oriented-such-that-the-net-degree-of-any)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a rather constructive approach. As long as $G$ contains undirected cycles, choose any one of them, and direct it in one of two possible ways. Once $G$ no longer contains undirected cycles, take maximal undirected paths instead. (This is where the imbalance occurs.)